# NPM package.json base / root property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a `package.json` property that can be used to specify the root folder that module resolution should start?

For example suppose we have an install in `node_modules/mypackage/src/file1`.  And all the files we want to import start under the `src` directory.  Can we specify something like:

```
 { 
    root: ./src/
 }
```

And then `require('mypackage/file1');`

Thoughts?

Comment: No... but you could make your own function to do that.

Comment: No, there is no property that can specify that. Why don't you just `exports.foo = require('./src/file1')` in `mypackage/index.js`? and `require('mypackage').foo`?

Comment: I could do that.  I was considering creating a index.ts and just compiling that into target.  I have a lot of files: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator ... The other option would be to compile everything to target and copy package.json to target as well, and then publish that ... Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: Created a feature request.  Please vote for it / thumbs it up if you like the idea: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21787

Comment: @Ole I don't think node even handles requests like that, pretty sure that would fall under the responsibility of `npm` and other package managers...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Node ultimately has to resolve the 'require()' statement so lets keep our fingers crossed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript modules support an experimental [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_exports) property in **package.json**. You can try something like:

```
{
  "exports": {
    "./": "./src/"
  }
}
```

Then imports like:

```
import file1Module from 'mypackage/file1'
```

Should load from `./node_modules/mypackage/src/file1.js`. If its not possible to alias the root you would have to do:

```
{
  "exports": {
    "./file1": "./src/file1.js"
  }
}
```

For every module or directory you wanted to alias.

As noted on your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21787#issuecomment-524709246).