# Excluding the 'src' folder from output during typescript compilation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

When running `tsc` how do we exclude the `src` folder (Root containing folder) from output?  I have the `outDir` set to `target` and instead of `target/src/file.ts` I would like `target/file.ts`?

Comment: Do you have all your code in the src folder?

Comment: I'm assuming this question is related to your [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51313753/1541563)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's related in the sense that I'm pursuing creating a clean `dist or target` directory to publish from...Would be a lot easier if there was a `base` package.json property though ... :)

Comment: @SimeonSmith yes currently the code is in the `src` folder.  I'm planning on building it all into a `target` folder and then copying package.json into that folder so that I can run npm publish from the target folder and have all the typescript modules be importable from there.

Comment: So in other words I would like to avoid compiling and then having to do additional moving of resources in order to create a clean `dist` folder to run `npm publish` from.

Comment: You should just be able to use tsc src to select everything in that folder and not output the src folder. What does your compile command look like right now?

Comment: It could be `tsc src/*`

Comment: Getting error TS6053: on the different attempts ...

Comment: I though perhaps I could use the `rootDir` options in tsconfig.json, but when I use that typescript complains that it does not contain the `test` directory ...

Comment: This is the target repository: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator

Comment: How about using the `"include"` option in your tsconfig? So something like `{"compilerOptions": { ... }, "include": [ "./src/" ]}`?

Comment: You're going to want a different tsc command to compile your tests. You can't do both at the same time and have the src not compile to the same folder. You can chain the commands though.

Comment: Yeah I'm using ts-node to both run nyc code coverage and mocha tests at the same time.  I have a follow up question about running the build using a separate tsconfig file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316731/compiler-option-for-specifying-the-name-of-the-tsconfig-json-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probably looking for the [rootDir](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir) tsconfig option. Specifically, in your case: `rootDir: 'src/'`, supposing your keeping *all* source files under ./src/ and your tsconfig.json at the level above src/.

Note however, `tsc` may silently ignore this setting if your actually importing files that aren't under `src/`, say for example you import your package.json from top level.