# Compiler option for specifying the name of the tsconfig.json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to have two `tsconfig.json` files.  One for testing and one for publishing.  Reading through a number of Typescript repository issues it seems like the flag for specifying the `tsconfig` file to use is `tsc --project tsconfig-test.json`, however when using this I get the following error:

```
  return path.replace(backslashRegExp, ts.directorySeparator);
                ^
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: TypeError: path.replace is not a function